# Me aparece el error: "error: statement cannot resolve adress of overloaded function"

Tags: c++

estaba aprendiendo el tema sobre la función "class" en C++, y mientras seguía un ejemplo hice esto:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

class shape{
int d, r;
public:

shape(int largo, int ancho){

d= largo;
r= ancho;

std::cout<<"El largo es: "<<d<<"\n\nEl ancho es: "<<r<<std::endl;
};
void area(){
std::cout<<"El area es: "<<d*r<<std::endl;
}

};

int main(){

shape square(30, 30);
square.area;    //problema

shape rectangle(10, 30);
rectangle.area;    //el mismo problema

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Estoy usando Code::Blocks 20.03
No estoy seguro si algo tiene  que ver el "std::cout<<", usando el "cout<<" aparece el mismo error: "error: statement cannot resolve adress of overloaded function". Gracias.

Comment: Te faltan los `()` para que el compilador entienda que  quieres llamar a la funcion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El único problema que noto es que `area` es una función. Por lo que debes llamarla con paréntesis. Así:

```
square.area();
rectangle.area();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvió, no pensé en eso jajaj.